# A question regarding Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Take $X = \mathbb{R}$, let $\mu$ be Lebesgue's measure in the real line, and  $f_n = \chi_{[n,\infty)}$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Why $\int_X f_n d\mu = \infty$ for all *n*?

Background of the question:

[image]

Comment: Do you know that $\int \chi_{[a,b]}(x) \, d\mu(x) = b-a$?

Comment: Look at the 'area' under the curve of $\chi_{[n,\infty)}$.

Comment: Presumably $\mu$ is Lebesgiue's measure. Well $\mu([n,\infty)\geq\mu([n,n+M))=M-n\xrightarrow{M\rightarrow\infty}\infty$. Notice the assumption $f_1\in L_1(\mu)$ in the theorems red. That is not satisfies by the sequence in your problem.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Currently I don't know. I think it depend on your $\mu$ here is $| \cdot |$, i.e., absolute value

Comment: Remember that $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: My question is the Lebesgue integral of this indicator set should be $\mu [a,b]$, but I am not sure the reason to conclude $\mu [a,b] = b-a$, since the absolute value is only one type of measure. We can also define other measures.

Answer (score 1):

Each $f_n$ has infinite support, and the value of $f_n(x)$ is bounded below everywhere on the support of $f_n$ (in particular, it takes a value of $1$).  How could the integral possibly be finite?